# Проблемы с подключение базы данных MySQL WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-core

Аннотация: Прошу прощения, если вопрос был задан некорректно.

Возможно проблема связана с таблицами, которые я создал.

Подключая БД с помощью команды в Консоле диспетчера пакетов NuGet:

**Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;user=root;password=[пароль];database=[название БД];"
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**

Были подключены все таблицы, кроме таблиц такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под этим типом я имею ввиду: Соединяющие таблицы, где оба поля являются и PK, и FK.

Остальные таблицы успешно подключились и появились в виде модели в проекте, а данные нет.

Как стоит делать соединяющие таблицы?

Например: У меня есть таблица с фильмами, а также есть таблица с жанрами.
Как мне к определенному фильму отнести определенные жанры?
Как должна выглядеть таблица?

Comment: Вы можете использовать для работы с MySql это https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/7.2.php  
`Как должна выглядеть таблица?` можете изучить пример https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/3.5.php  код подойдет для библиотеки из ссылки что выше. Создайте одну модель которая содержит списки из жанров и фильмов

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Т. к. в этой таблице нет колонки с полезной нагрузкой (payload), то вполне можно обходиться без лишней сущности. Обычно пишут наподобие: `movie.Genres.Add(genre1)` или `genre.Movies.Add(movie1)` - связи будут созданы автоматически.

Comment: [Many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#many-to-many-relationships) - ссылка на документацию, подтверждающая, что для простых соединителных таблиц (join table) класс-сущность не генерируется.

Comment: Кстати, укажите используемую версию EF. Начиная с  EF Core 7 можно вручную настраивать шаблоны: [Custom Reverse Engineering Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: Но если эта соединительная сущность очень нужна (хочется в коде через неё задавать связи), то следует просто руками описать её в коде C#.

Comment: [Many-to-many relationships without mapped join entities are now scaffolded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes#many-to-many). В разделе Mitigations описано, что следует предпринять.